# How to generate immutable Java objects using XJC?

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

Since I switch to Java 8 I start using 'parallelStream' on collections. 
I want to generate immutable Java objects to have 100% conviction that state of paralelly procesed object is/was not change.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: The 'useless' parts should've been fixed in the latest plugin version (1.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comment to this question someone give me a link to GitHub project and it perfectly meets my expectation:
https://github.com/sabomichal/immutable-xjc